# WebGL: texture from div

Tags: html, webgl

I want to show some objects, which texture will be dynamically generated. Is there a method to create a texture from a div element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a div element as a WebGL texture, however, you can easily generate your texture using 2D Canvas or OpenGL's render targets.

Comment: I need to add some dynamic text and compose some images on the texture. Is it doable the way you propose? I'm just starting with WebGl and using GLGE, so I don't know all the details yet.

Comment: Yes. HTML5 Canvas2D allows you to draw images, render texts, draw shapes and even apply some bindings!
You can also use Canvas as an OpenGL viewport with a 2D orthographic projection and load it as a dynamic texture, but the first method is recommended :)